# How to get all folders and subfolders from a sharepoint library using web services

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, web-services, designer-workflow

I'm using workflow with a rest webservice to retrieve all empty folders for a document library.

We want to email the administrator when a certain folder does not contain a document.

We have managed to created a workflow and retrieve all the empty folders in a document library, it does not retrieve the subfolders.

We have used this soluton:

```
   https://<SPURL>/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/site/subsite/library')/Folders
```

[image]
If you look at the results it displays it only shows the parrent folders, is there any way to retrieve one list with all the folders and sub folders?

Thanks in advance and kind regards,
Raymond Peters

Comment: [This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-get-the-subfolders-from-the-document-library-in-share/) might help you

Comment: Thank you but this solution only queries subfolders within a folder. I'm looking for a solutions that runs from the top of the library and then retrieves all of the parent folders and subfolders.

Comment: You'll probably need to get the parent folders first, then go through each one to get the subfolders. This would probably need to be recursive as well to get any subfolders in the subfolder.

Comment: Yes I can try this approach, would have bin nice to have a webservice which returns them all would save me some time. Thank you for the quick reply.